# CorePlot axisLine and gridLine length too long

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, grid, core-plot, axis

I'm using CorePlot for my current project and  its amazing. 
The only problem I came across is the length of the axis and grids.
I'm only using a positiv coordinate system with labels on the left and bottom side.
And my problem is the length of the axis and grids in direction to my labels.
I tried to use:

```
axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"-value");
axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"-value");
```

or

```
x.labelOffset = value;
y.labelOffset = value;
```

but this is only setting the distance of my labels different and not affecting the grids length.

In my example the `y-axis` and there `grid` overlaps my `label:@{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`

[image]

Did somebody dealed with the same problem? THX for all answer to the right way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `visibleRange` and `gridLinesRange` to limit the axes and grid lines, respectively. See the "Control Chart" in the *Plot Gallery* example app for sample code.