# Core Plot grid lines moving past the axis

Tags: ios8, core-plot

So, this is an old problem but no longer solvable the old way. I [found it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011194/coreplot-axisline-and-gridline-length-too-long) and a few others.

This is a two, part question. First, through lots of searches, I learned that I should make the visible range small and the actual range large to increase the clipping area so the labelling shows. This has a side effect of making the plot area's lines extend out, with the labels. The examples in the folder are outdated, they have orthogonalPosition as an axis property, which no longer exists, but used to be the solution.

(2nd question) Core Plot doesn't have updated documentation, or examples, I've been using guess-and-check for hours at a time, per piece of my graph, while trying to find examples that are up-dated. Is there a resource for this? The wiki just has setup and the api, but the api won't tell you "you need to set the base value for the areaFill to show", yet in contrast, it automatically has defaults for making the ticks show. Ticks vs intervals is easy to figure out, but I had to eventually figure it out, it wasn't documented either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `orthogonalPosition` property is the new version. It was part of the API updates made with the 2.0 release. There is a [wiki page](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Core-Plot-API-Changes-Between-Versions-1.x-and-2.x) with details of the changes. The [change log](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/documentation/changelog.markdown) is also online showing the history of the major changes over time.

The current API docs are always available online at https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.github.io. There are separate pages for the Mac and iOS/tvOS versions to account for differences between AppKit and UIKit. Core Plot includes several example apps that demonstrate many of the important concepts. The *Plot Gallery* app contains the widest array of features and runs on Mac, iOS, and tvOS. If you notice deficiencies in the API documentation like the `areaFill` example in the question, please open an issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues).

I'm not aware of any comprehensive high-level documentation that walks through everything in detail. I've considered writing a book about it, but that's a big project and I haven't jumped in yet. For now, Core Plot includes the API docs, the example apps, and several [wiki pages](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki). There are also various blog posts online about different topics, but those vary in quality and whether they've been kept up-to-date with newer Core Plot versions.

Comment: Thanks Eric! The changelog, I never considered. I did see that wiki, and the api, but the api is pretty lacking. It's the "thing" I mention that tells you, everything but how to use it, lol. 

It seems I used XYGraph but no XYAxis, which explains why I never saw that property. Examples had it on the axes themselves, which I have, just not subclassed types. 

I've just re-cast the CPTAxis to CPTXYAxis, added the orthogonalPosition to be 0 for both, and it's still extending past the axis. I will do some reading and more guess-and-check before I claim anything. You still helped a lot!

Comment: I think I figured it out. Kinda. The tick lines, they were fine, but I needed the x and y themselves to not go past.

I modified RenderInContext to respect existence of orthogonal by offsetting rendering of the axis, and shortening theVisibleRange.location by the orthoganol as a floatValue, wrapped in @() and other converts to (NSNumber * _Nonnull) because of the new swift-mimicking.
Admittedly it's a hack based on not knowing what orthogonal is meant to do, other than offset the graph.